# SignalR in Angular2 (Typescript) - Import Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having problems using signalR in an Angular2-Typescript app. I have it working fine in a previous Angular 1 app. My problem is with the importing.

I have the intellisense working but the strong typing doesn't seem to map to the original js file correctly.

In node_modules, I have these two folders (edited here for space):

```
├───jquery
│   │   jquery.d.ts
│   │   LICENSE.txt
│   │   package.json
│   │   README.md
│   │
│   ├───dist
│   │       core.js
│   │       jquery.js
│
└───signalr
        jquery.signalR.js
        jquery.signalR.min.js
        package.json
        signalr.d.ts
```

The jquery.d.ts file is this one:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

The signalr.d.ts file is this one:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/signalr/signalr.d.ts

**Note**: I have edited the signalr.d.ts to add this at the end, otherwise I can't import it:

```
declare var sr : JQueryStatic;

declare module 'signalr'{
    export = sr;
}
```

In systemjs.config.js I use this to import signalr:

```
map: {
'signalr': 'npm:signalr/jquery.signalR.js'
}
```

And then in my component I use:

```
import * as $ from 'signalr'
```

I then have access to intellisense, for instance:

[image]

However, there are problems. If I use:

```
console.log($.hubConnection);
```

I get undefined.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
map: {
      'ms-signalr-client': 'npm:ms-signalr-client/jquery.signalR.min.js',
      'jquery': 'npm:jquery/jquery.min.js'
}
```

in your ts

```
    import 'ms-signalr-client';
    import * as $ from 'jquery'; 
    ...
    $.hubConnection
    ...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked. Thank you. In systemjs.config I pointed it to 'jquery/dist/jquery.js' and when choosing 'Go to Definition' in the component I am taken to the file: jquery.d.ts. PS. I had previously amended the package.json file to include the typings reference: "typings": "./jquery.d.ts".

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, you should point to `jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` and in typings.json `"jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160929162922",
    "signalr": "registry:dt/signalr#2.2.0+20160509082439"`. Sorry for confusion, was just in hurry